# How to update array object in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I want to update localStorage selected object quantity when this object is already exist. It'll be change trigger handleAddCart condational statement inside else if.
***handleAddCart > else if

```
//this append function for concat 
const appendToStorage = (name, data) => {
    var prevItems = localStorage.getItem(name)
    try{
        prevItems = JSON.parse(prevItems);
    } catch (e){
        prevItems = []
    }
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(prevItems.concat(data)))
}
```

This is submit handler

```
const handleAddCart = () => {
    //when there is no array stored
    if (localStorage.getItem('cartList') === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('cartList',JSON.stringify(cartList))
    }
    if (cartItem.size && cartItem.quantity) {
        //1st when there is no array
        if (!localData) {
            appendToStorage('cartList', cartItem)
        } else if (localData.some((item) => item.cartId === cartItem.cartId)) {
            //when array contain same object
            var itemPrice = localData.find((item) => item.cartId === cartItem.cartId);
            
        } else {
            //concat new object
            appendToStorage('cartList', cartItem)
        }

        history.push('/shop')
        setItemSize(null)
        setSelectWarning(false);
    } else{
        setSelectWarning(true)
    }
}
```

cartItem is an object & cartList is an array.
cartItem is Like this-

```
CartItem = {
        name: '',
        cartId: '',
        price: '',
        size: '',
        quantity: 1,
        img: ''
    }
CartList = []
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: everything is okey. but i can't update object. please see handleAddCart line 11(with comment) > else if  > where is want update object

Answer (score 1):

```
var sameItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.cartList);
            for(var i = 0;i < sameItem.length; i++){
                if (cartItem.cartId === sameItem[i].cartId) {
                    sameItem[i].quantity += cartItem.quantity;
                    break;
                }
            }
            localStorage.setItem('cartList',JSON.stringify(sameItem))
```